# Scala swing wait for a button press after pressing a button

Tags: scala, swing, user-interface, button

So What I want to do is to press a button and inside the ButtonClicked Event I want to wait completing the event, until I press a specific button/one of the specified buttons.
I also know that there are some similar questions to this topic but I wasnt able to find a fix out of the answers

So basically this:

```
reactions += {
    case event.ButtonClicked(`rollDice`) =>
        some code ...
        wait for one of the specified buttons to be pressed and then continue
        some code ...
```

Is there an easy way to solve this problem without the use of threads?

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly some abstractions you could set up around the event layer, but you asked for "easy", so my suggestion is to set a flag/state when the dice are rolled, and then check for that flag in the other buttons' event handler.

```scala
private var postDiceRollState: Option[InfoRelatedToRollDice] = None

reactions += {
  case event.ButtonClicked(`rollDice`) =>
    // capture whatever info you need to pass along to the later button handler
    val relevantInfo = /* some code... */

    // store that info in the "state"
    postDiceRollState = Some(relevantInfo)

  case event.ButtonClicked(other) if isPostDiceRollButton(other) =>
    // when the other button gets clicked, pull the relevant info from your "state"
    postDiceRollState match {
      case Some(relevantInfo) =>
        postDiceRollState = None // clear state
        doInterestingStuff(relevantInfo) // "some code..."
      case None =>
        // nothing happens if you didn't roll the dice first
    }
}
```

Note: I represented the "flag" as an Option, under the assumption that you might have some information you want to capture about the `rollDice` event. If you don't actually have anything to put in there, you could represent your state as `private var didRollDice: Boolean = false` and set/clear would be setting it to true/false respectively.